# Does not implement interface member Error

Tags: c#, api, interface, implementation

Here's my code, VS2012 C# Express is complaining about the non implementation of the two members in the interface PISDK._DEventPipeEvents, which is pasted here quickly:

```
    namespace PISDK
{
    [Guid("9E679FD2-DE8C-11D3-853F-00C04F45D1DA")]
    [InterfaceType(2)]
    [TypeLibType(4096)]
    public interface _DEventPipeEvents
    {
        [DispId(2)]
        void OnNewValue();
        [DispId(1)]
        void OnOverflow(object vtEvent, OverflowCauseConstants Cause);
    }
}
```

and here's my code:

```
class PointListEventPipeEventReceiver : PISDK._DEventPipeEvents
{
    private PISDK.EventPipe eventPipe;

    public PointListEventPipeEventReceiver(PISDK.EventPipe eventPipe)
    {
        this.eventPipe = eventPipe;
    }

    public void PISDK._DEventPipeEvents.OnNewValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New value event");
        handleNewValue(eventPipe);
    }

    public void PISDK._DEventPipeEvents.OnOverFlow(object vtEvent, PISDK.OverflowCauseConstants Cause)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void handleNewValue(PISDK.EventPipe eventPipe)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handling new value");
        Array eventObjs = eventPipe.TakeAll();
        Console.WriteLine("eventObjs.Length==" + eventObjs.Length);
        foreach (PISDK.PIEventObject piEventObj in eventObjs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(piEventObj.EventData as PISDK.PointValue);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm at a loss here, any help is nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to getting the case wrong in "overflow", it looks like you're trying to apply the `public` access modifier to an explicit interface member implementation.  You can either implement the member implicitly as a public member, or explicitly, but not both.

Implicit implementation:

```
public void OnOverflow(object vtEvent, PISDK.OverflowCauseConstants Cause) 
{ 
    throw new NotImplementedException(); 
}
```

Explicit implementation:

```
void PISDK._DEventPipeEvents.OnOverflow(object vtEvent, PISDK.OverflowCauseConstants Cause) 
{ 
    throw new NotImplementedException(); 
}
```

Comment: This was more the issue I didn't know about, being new to C#. Many thanks.

Comment: @cdietschrun you're welcome.  It took me some time to wrap my head around this concept when I was new to C#, but now that I do understand it, I use it all the time.  It's a powerful and much-underappreciated technique.

Answer (score 5):

Your implementation uses `OnOverFlow` with a capital `F` instead of a lowercase one in the interface. The method should be called `OnOverflow`.

Comment: If you're new to C#, you'll need to remember it is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Tim: Or right click on the interface `Foo : IFoo` and choose `implement the interface`, which guarantees correct spelling.

Comment: @DannyChen - Yep.  I completely forgot about that option.